# C# スプラッシュウインドウを作り表示させても、きれいに表示されない

Tags: c#, form

お世話になります。

C#(.Net Framework)2019にて、アプリケーションを作っています。長い処理をさせているときにスプラッシュスクリーンを表示させようと、ラベルとPictureBoxを使用して簡単なSSを作ったのですが、いざ表示させて
メインの処理に入ると、SSの描画が終わらないらしく、ラベルとPictureBoxの部分が透過して
表示され、処理が終了するまでそのままの状態で表示されてしまいます。

[image: 表示させたいSSはこれです。]
↑これが作成したSSです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
↑実際に表示させると、コントロールの部分が透過しています。

スクリーンショットでも撮れなかったので、エディタ上のデザインを表示させていますが、実際には
上記画像の黒い部分が抜けている状態です。

考え方では、SSが描画が終了したらメインの処理を行えばよいと思うのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか。

ちなみに、SSはShowDialogではなく、Showで表示させ、同じメソッド内で表示し、処理が完了したら閉じるようになっています。

下記がコードです。

```
private void reload()
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fbd.Description = "ファイルを検索するルートフォルダを選択してください。";
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    string stSelectedPath = fbd.SelectedPath;
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(stSelectedPath))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("指定されたフォルダは存在しません。", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    SplashScreen ss = new SplashScreen();　　　　// ここで表示するも、きれいに出ない。
        ss.Show(this);

    if (!PlayListModel.reload(stSelectedPath))
    {
        ss.Close();
        ss = null;
        MessageBox.Show("データベースへの登録に失敗しました。", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    ss.Close();
    ss = null;

    this.review();

    MessageBox.Show("読み込みが完了しました。", AppName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async/await 構文を使うのが良いかなと思います。
`SplashScreen` の描画完了を待っているわけではなく、描画と同時進行で読み込み処理を行います。読み込み処理中にUIを操作することもできます。不都合な場合は `Enabled` を `false` にするとよいかもしれません。

```
async void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Reload();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
        Application.Exit();
    }
}

async Task Reload()
{
    var ss = new SplashScreen();
    ss.Show(this);

    var succeded = await Task.Run(() => HeavyTask());
    ss.Close();

    if (!succeded)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

もしくは `Application.DoEvents` で描画の完了を強制できるようです。こちらは読み込み処理中にアプリケーションがフリーズしたようになります。あまりに長いとOSから応答なしと判断されるかもしれません。

```
async void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Reload();
}

async void Reload()
{
    var ss = new SplashScreen();
    ss.Show(this);
    Application.DoEvents();

    var succeded = HeavyTask();
    ss.Close();

    if (!succeded)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。DoEventsにしたら、あっさりできました。VBAなんかでも同じことをやっていたはずなのですが、どうも忘れていてしまったようです。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。